# Deforming $\text{id}: S^1 \to S^1$ to the symmetry $S^1 \to S^1$ such that $x \mapsto -x$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**I am trying to find a deformation retraction of $\text{id}: S^1 \to S^1$ to the symmetry $S^1 \to S^1$ such that $x \mapsto -x$.** I guess this deformation of maps has to respect all homotopy rules, i.e. $F(x,0)=x, F(x,1)=-x$ and $F(y,t)=y$ for any $x>0$, for $y<0$ and $t\in [0,1]$. I am struggling to find such a homotopy. What I thought was the following,
$$F(x,t)=x(1-t)-xt$$
and we see that indeed $F(x,0)=x$ and $F(x,1)=-x$ but this is true for $x>0$. But how to show the last part that $F(y,t)=y$ where $y$. Note that I am a bit confused with the notation here. Since I am in the circle what does it mean negative $x$ since $x$ can be viewed as complex number such that $|x|=1$?

Also what is the relation of the above with the projective plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i understood is that your are trying to find a homotopy of $id_{S^1}$ to $a:S^1\to S^1$ such that $a(x)=-x$. This is the antipodal map.

Such a homotopy is $F:S^1\times I\to S^1$ with $F(x,t)=e^{i\pi t}x$.
It's is clearly continuous, $F(x,0)=x$ and $F(x,1)=-x=a(x)$.

Also the projective plane $\mathbb RP^2$ is the quotient space $S^1/_{x\equiv a(x)}$

Comment: It seems that in the above I was trying to find a deformation retract which is not what the exercise asks. Now, your answer is true, but isnt mine as well? I repeat that I proposed $F(x,t)=x(1-t)-xt$? It seems that indeed $F(x,0)=x$ and $F(x,1)=-x$.

Comment: Your "homotopy" $F$ does not lie in the circle $S^1$ because the circle is not a convex set.